# Restoring scroll event using JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to restore **scroll event** or **scrollbar position** after page refresh/reload. Here is my code, but I can't make it work. Tried it on JSFiddle but no luck. Please help! JavaScript code below.

Note: I have a hidden `<input>` element with an id of *scrolled*, and a `<textarea>` with an id of *textAreaInput*.

```
    function saveScroll()
    {
      some code
    }

    function restoreScroll()
    {
      some code
    }

    window.onunload = saveScroll;
    window.onload = restoreScroll;
```

Comment: Is your problem with storing the scroll value to access it again? Or is it the scrolling itself?

Comment: Add some debug statements (console.log or alert) to see the value of scrollTop at unload time, and the value of the "scrolled" input element at load time.

Comment: @Toast : I'd want the scrollbar to stay on its previous position after reload of page. When I run this code on JSFiddle, the scrollbar goes back to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you don't actually set the `#scrolled` value when producing the page because its value set in `saveScroll` never reaches the server. Remember that when a page is reloaded, all the DOM data from the previous load are discarded.

I'd figure that you could try setting this value in a `document.cookie` but you need to check if this is going to work. Another option is to use `window.sessionStorage` if one is available in the target environment.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJdSw/) for you to play with. Scroll the textarea and refresh the page. You can see the debug output in your firebug or devtools console.